# How to sort an array object based on the key value?

Tags: javascript

Below is an array object I would like to sort based on the first key value of each of the object in each of the array.

```
var beforeSort = [{
"James": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"William": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"Cindy": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"Apple": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"Timmy": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
}];
```

The result that I want to achieve will be as below:

```
 var afterSort = [{
"Apple": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"Cindy": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"James": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
"Timmy": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
},{
 "William": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value",
"key": "value"
}];
```

Is it technically possible?

Comment: Many things are technically possible in programming. Often the first step is to figure out what sort of logic you're trying to implement, and second, to try writing some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of common keys and filter the unknown key from all keys for sorting.

```
var commonKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var keyA = Object.keys(a).filter(k => !commonKeys.includes(k))[0],
        keyB = Object.keys(b).filter(k => !commonKeys.includes(k))[0];

    return keyA.localeCompare(keyB);
})
```

Comment: I think OP just wants `Object.keys(a)[0]`